# SSH productivity question about bash-alias: how can I queue a command (screen -x) after SSH login?

Tags: ssh, bash

I have bash alias set up to connect me to my various servers/ports easily, but I realize about 90% of the time I type in screen -x immediately after logging in.

Can I queue a text command to be sent to the current window instead of being executed after the current command?

I generally type in my alias, then screen -x right away where the text is queued and sent to the logged in SSH session as soon as the connection is ready.

The following alias will just execute screen -x after I close the ssh connection.

```
logmein() {
        ssh me@me.me -p 14832
        screen -x
}
```

Any help is appreciated, or places to look : )

Comment: I suppose, the answer is here: https://serverfault.com/questions/21806/how-can-i-launch-a-screen-session-with-a-command-over-ssh-on-a-remote-server-from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal of immediately executing the "screen -x" command after the SSH connection is established, you can modify your alias to use SSH's "-t" option to force pseudo-terminal allocation.

```
logmein() {
    ssh -t me@me.me -p 14832 "screen -x"
}
```

With this modification, the "screen -x" command will be executed in the same SSH session right after the connection is established. This should give you the behavior you're looking for.